# java.lang.module.FindException: Module processed.jcommander not found, required by org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver error using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-java

I  am trying to run selenium script with java language but facing the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module processed.jcommander not found, required by org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module processed.jcommander not found, required by org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver
```

...implies that [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) jars/binaries were not configured properly within the framework.

---

### Solution

In such cases, the two basic steps to be taken are as follows:

- Delete the *`module-info.java`* file (incase you have one)
- Move the Selenium jar from the *Modulepath* to the ***Classpath*** (within Project > Properties: Java Build Path, tab Libraries)